# BLUEPRINT Google Grid Gallery rtl support

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm u using Google Grid Gallery for one of my project using [plugin tutorial](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/03/21/google-grid-gallery/).

As this project is based in multiple languages, I am unable to make the grid for rtl (arabic). The grid made by the javascript puts the li item on the left, I want it to be on right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@bimal Google-grid-gallery is using masonry and i check the use of masonry, you can do is add the line

```
originLeft:false,
```

in your file cbpGridGallery.js like

```
new Masonry( grid, {
            itemSelector: 'li',
            originLeft:false,
            columnWidth: grid.querySelector( '.grid-sizer' )
        });
```

ALso update your masonry js so it support orginLeft
Thanks :)